# How to display timecodes with iMovie 10.0.7 N

Tags: preferences, imovie

On discussion forums, I read that I have to go to iMovie Preferences and ask to display timecodes.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2129?locale=en_US&viewlocale=fr_FR

But my preferences window only contains two checkboxes, none of them related to timecodes.

Do you know how to see the timecode for a given image in a movie ?

Thanks for your help !